# Record / number a formula in a cell, not to be deleted google spreadsheet - appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to this apps script and I'm trying to create a function that leaves a formula nested / recorded inside a cell since the database is used by people who are not experts in the formulation and this would prevent them from deleting the fomulations

The problem is that the formula I am trying to record in the cell contains quotes "" and when executing the script it marks me an error, when modifying the script and removing the quotes if it records the formula but with an error (because the quotes are missing)

I hope you can help me as I see they are experts in the subject.

The sequence that I have so far is this:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var cell = sheet.getRange("H1");
  cell.setFormula("=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1boU9bEyqJkLbf895QavKEzeZ4sLle2qoqepeZeJVV8/edit#gid=0";"sucursal 0007!B4")");

}
```

From the error I understand that it is because of the quotes that are inside the formula:

[image]

When I remove the quotes if you save the formula on sheet 1 but with an error (because you do not have the quotes required by the formula)

[image]

The correct formula that I need is this:

```
=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bpUJbEyqJkALbf995QavKEzeZ4sLle2qoqepeZaJVV8/edit#gid=0";"sucursal 0007!B4")
```

Comment: Maybe Use single quotes `'` and  try escaping the `"` with `\"`;  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194668/parse-error-from-using-setvalue-or-setformula-to-set-a-formula-containing-a-qu

Answer (score 0):

For Line 7 please try:

```
  cell.setFormula('=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1boU9bEyqJkLbf895QavKEzeZ4sLle2qoqepeZeJVV8/edit#gid=0";"sucursal 0007!B4")');
```

i.e. the formula inside single quotes.

Grant permission if required.